# read integers from file and store it in array in java

Tags: java, unix, input

I have a file with data like in the picture:

[image]

and I need to store just numbers on an array , but when I print the array the output shows:

> 0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   .......

```java
File namesData = new File("data.txt");
Scanner input = new Scanner(namesData);
int array[] = new int[32469];
int i = 0;
while (input.hasNextInt()) {
    array[i] = input.nextInt();
    i++ ;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect `hasNextInt()` to succeed  the first time?

Comment: Your question can be improved by including a sample of your data as text in the question itself, instead of linking to an image of it.  Links die, and images aren't searchable.

Answer (score 1):

`hasNextInt` is not testing to see if there an int *somewhere* up ahead; it is testing to see if the *next* thing in the file is an `int`.  Since the first thing in your file is *not* an int, the loop never gets entered.

Using a debugger would have made this clear (the *what* if not the *why*).

Comment: Try hasNextLine()

Comment: Replace hasNextInt() with hasNextLine() and then replace array[i] = input.nextInt(); with input.next();input.next();input.nextInt(); and see what happens.  Also, read your exception text carefully.  Exceptions have an amazing amount of very specific info in them, it's not just an "I Crashed" indication!

Comment: i got java.util.InputMismatchException